# Tensoring locally free sheaves - global sections

Tags: schemes, coherent-sheaves

Suppose you two locally free sheaves $L,M$ on an integral scheme $X$ over $k$. Is it true that the map

$L(X) \otimes M(X) \to ( L \otimes M)(X)$

Is injective? The map is formally induced by the general map from a presheaf to its sheafification, recalling that the tensor of two sheaves is the sheafification of the presheaf which is "openwise" $U \mapsto L(U)\otimes M(U)$.

Concretely, is just thinking a product of sections in the tensor sheaf.

My try:

1. Let U be a open such that both L,M are free. Then the tensor sheaf coincides with the tensor presheaf, because for a ring $A$, $f \in A$, and $r,s$ natural holds
   $(A^{rs})_f \simeq A^r_f \otimes A^s_f $
   By the exactness of localisation.
2. Suppose $\sum s_i \otimes t_i $ goes to zero. Then it's stalks are everywhere null, and in particular by 1 there exist an open set $U$ such that $\sum s_i \otimes t_i | U = 0$. 
   Recall that $X$ is integral, thus $U$ is dense.
3. I would like now to conclude the restriction map to $U$ is injective, because is the tensor of two injective maps over $k$. Is is true?

Best,
Andrea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not injective in general. Consider $X = \Bbb P^1_k$, $L = M = O_X(1)$. Then $L(X) = M(X) \cong k^2$ so that $L(X) \otimes_k M(X) \cong k^4$, but $L \otimes_{O_X} M \cong O_X(2)$ has a $3$-dimensional space of global sections.

A presheaf $F$ is said to be *separated* when the sheafification map $F \to F^+$ is injective. The example above is a *non-separated* presheaf $U \mapsto L(U) \otimes_{O_X(U)} M(U)$. See also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105232/tensor-product-of-sheaves-separated).

---

Let me call $f$ the natural map $L(X) \otimes_{O_X(X)} M(X) \to (L \otimes_{O_X} M)(X)$.
In your second step, when you are writing $\sum s_i \otimes t_i | U = 0$, I guess that you mean 
$$\mathrm{Res}_U^X \left[ f\left(\sum_i s_i \otimes t_i \right)\right] = 0$$ 
But even if the restriction map $\mathrm{Res}_U^X$ was injective (as you mention in your 3rd point), you've proven nothing, since you don't know if $f$ is injective. This is precisely what you are trying to prove. Unless I misunderstood your reasoning.

Comment: What's wrong in my argument?

Comment: @frame95 : please see the edit.

Comment: Answering your edit, I implicitly used that $f$ is an isomorphism on stalks in the second step, thus the stalks of $h=\sum s_i \otimes t_i$ are themselves null. By the "locally-is-a-sheaf" property of the first step, I then conclude that there is an open set on which $h$ is itself null.

Comment: @frame95 : in any case, even if you have $h\vert_U = 0$ for any open $U$ in a given open cover of $X$, this does not mean that $h$ is zero, precisely because the presheaf $U \mapsto L(U) \otimes M(U)$ is only a presheaf and not a sheaf in general (you don't have existence and uniqueness of gluing).

Comment: For instance if $X = \{x,y\}$ and if we consider the non-separated presheaf $$P(\varnothing) = \{*\}, \; P(\{x\}) = P(\{y\}) := \Bbb Z,\; P(X) = \Bbb Z^3,$$ we can have $h(\{x\}) = h(\{y\}) = 0$ but $h(\{x,y\}) = (0,0,1) \neq 0$.

Comment: But restriction maps of the tensor are in this case tensor of restriction maps of the single sheaves, thus are injective maps. Indeed, if V,W are vector spaces over k and $V\toV', W \to W'$ are injective, then $V\otimes W \to V' \otimes W'$ is injective. I didn't use the sheaf property!

Comment: @frame95 : what are these injective maps $V \to V'$ in our case? Recall that $L(X) = k^2$ but $L$ is a line bundle, i.e. locally free of _rank $1$_, so I don't see how $L(X) \to L(U)$ is injective in general!

Comment: Now I see the point... I wrongly thought that restricting to a dense subset was injective (in the integral case) not only for the structural sheaf, but for a general line bundle. Thank you!

Comment: @frame95 : you're welcome. Don't forget to accept/upvote the answer, so that it doesn't remain in the "unanswered list" ;-)